# Casting loaded class

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, classloader

I'm fairly new to this concept of class loading, but I wanted to try to load a class and cast it.

And example is:

```
public class foo {
    public void fah() {
        System.out.println("blah");
    }
}
```

Now I already have a custom class loader, and that returns a Class. How do I cast that returned class to "foo" so that I can use it's methods and variables. I've seen the getMethod() method of Classes, is that what I am supposed to use instead of trying to cast it to Foo?

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded the Class but you need to instantiate an Object in order to be able to access it as a foo.

Check out the Java API documents for the Class class, specifically the newInstace() and getConstructor() methods, because these will be the keys.  When you invoke a constructor via reflection, you will be able to cast the result to your desired class and then treat it like any other instance of foo.

Comment: Something such as, Class c = loadClass("someClass"); Foo = (Foo) c.newInstance(); ?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need an identifier after "Foo" like Foo f=(Foo)c.newInstance();  For this to work, class Foo MUST have a constructor that takes no arguments.  If you need to pass arguments, you'll need to use the getConstructor() or getConstructors() method on the Class object.

Comment: Woops, I forgot about the identifier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you load the class you'll have the reflection stuff to find and call the method with the desired parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I know I have the method.invoke() route I can go with, but I was wondering if it's possible to just cast it instead of adding that extra line.

Answer (score 0):

For a class with default constructor. You have to do something like this:

```
Class claz = Class.forName("com.a.b.C", true, classLoader);

Object[] paramObject = new Object[]{file};
Class<?>[]paramType =  new Class[]{file.getClass()};    

Method method = claz.getMethod("methodName", paramType);
method.invoke(claz.newInstance(), paramObject);
```

The corresponding java class will look like:

```
package com.a.b;
import java.io.File;

public class C {
    public C(){}
    public void methodName(File file){
    }
}
```

for class with constructor:

Try to use `getConstructor()` for getting appropriate constructor and the calling `newInstace()` on it.

**Note**

While using reflection APIs always keep the appropriate type in mind. i.e. `Integer` != `int` because autoboxing is not present.

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to get the value of a field, how would I extract that value out of the java.lang.reflect.Field object created from claz.getField("somefield");

Answer (score 0):

If you load a class thru reflection it is because you don't know the actual class at compile time, so as seen in a comment (in another answer):

```
Class c = loadClass("Foo");
Foo f = (Foo) c.newInstance();
```

makes no sense, as you already have Foo statically accessible in the class path, just do

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

Again you use reflection for when you DON'T have statically bound access to a class. (or don't know whether you do or not) Consider this:

The class defined as

```
public class Foo implements SomeInterface {
    public void fah() {
        System.out.println("blah");
    }
}
```

Now access this Foo class through reflection but hold on to it as a `SomeInterface` object.

```
Class c = loadClass("Foo");

SomeInterface i = (SomeInterface)c.newInstance();
```

Here I have SomeInterface that is implemented by "Foo". My code is compiled against SomeInterface so i can reference the methods defined in the interface, but i have no idea what implementation class "Foo" is, other than by name.